Cpu usage is high
I have a site that is designed with WordPress. On this site, when I activate WooCommerce, the CPU consumption increases drastically and it gives the following errors in the error log:
---WordPress database error Lost connection to MySQL server during query for query UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = '1719064615' WHERE option_name = '_transient_timeout_woocommerce_blocks_asset_api_script_data_ssl' made by shutdown_action_hook, do_action('shutdown'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\Assets\Api->update_script_data_cache, set_transient, update_option
--- WordPress database error Malformed packet for query SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'wc_pending_batch_processes' LIMIT 1 made by shutdown_action_hook, do_action('shutdown'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, Automattic\WooCommerce\Internal\DataStores\Orders\LegacyDataCleanup->__call, call_user_func_array, Automattic\WooCommerce\Internal\DataStores\Orders\LegacyDataCleanup->maybe_reset_state, Automattic\WooCommerce\Internal\BatchProcessing\BatchProcessingController->is_enqueued, Automattic\WooCommerce\Internal\BatchProcessing\BatchProcessingController->get_enqueued_processors, get_option
I have also checked all the plugins and other things. Please guide me how to fix the problem.
Thanks

Please post COMPLETE TEXT result of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_options;  and your LAST 100 lines of Error Log - for analysis.
